# ssh paul@storage002: Load key "C:\\Users\\Paul/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied

Tags: ssh, rsa, password-less

I'm trying to setup my Synology for SSH access without passwords but can't seem to get it right.

I've followed [this](https://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/01/15/ssh-into-your-synology-diskstation-with-ssh-keys/) description for setting it up on my NAS to the letter and succeeded partly. It does try to send the private key to the server but on loading it from the local id_rsa file it fails with 'access denied'. This is probably because I've denied the 'Administrators' group to access the file. If however I allow the 'Administrators' to access the file SSH complains the rights on the file are too open.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su] instead of here.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't understand exactly what caused it but it has something to do with security of WIndows 10. I've been busy for hours fiddling around with 'deny' and 'allow' of rights on the id_rsa file but nothing seemed to work. I've now changed the inherited right to local rights on the object itself and allowed 'administrators' to access the file fully and look it works. It's not clear to me why.